# Stripe API Update DRAFT invoice for subscription (PHP)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using PHP and have a webhook generated with `invoice.created`.  When the invoice is created, Stripe lets the draft invoice sit there for about an hour which gives us time to edit the invoice or adjust it.  I use this time to check the database (via webhook) to see how many referrals this person has in the system to the adjust the coupons accordingly.  I can't seem to adjust the invoice properly as I get errors in all the ways I have tried, which are:

$inv = {the invoice id and I get no error from the invoice ID being incorrect

```
define('STRIPE_API_KEY', 'sk_test_******************'); 

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
    STRIPE_API_KEY
);

$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['discounts.coupon' => '20OFF']
);
```

Error is unknown object discounts.coupon

and

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['discount' => '20OFF']
);
```

> Error = **Fatal error**:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_hsX1QTOxzWMiQn) Received unknown parameter: discount. Did you mean discounts? thrown in **/home/searchoscn/public_html/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php** on line **38**

and

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['coupon' => '20OFF']
);
```

> ERROR = **Fatal error**:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_yEwwOLoukR6j6Z) Received unknown parameter: coupon thrown in **/home/searchoscn/public_html/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php** on line **38**

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['discounts' => ['coupon' => '20OFF']]
);
```

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_IDRP1Rjv1YoBZR) Invalid array thrown in **/home/searchoscn/public_html/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php** on line **38**

I'm pretty sure I need to use 'discounts' but don't know how to structure the array to pass the coupon properly.

Trying to predict some questions or comments:

Yes, I do have an existing coupon with id of 20OFF.  This is for 20% off

$inv does fetch the correct ID of the invoice at the time the webhook is sent.

Here is [the link of the API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update) that I've been reading, but it isn't very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['discounts.coupon' => '20OFF']
);
```

try:

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    ['discounts' => ['coupon' => $couponId]]
);
```

It looks like it must be the id of the coupon and not the customer facing code, e.g. `20OFF`.

You would be able to get the id of the coupon from the dashboard (https://dashboard.stripe.com/coupons/) or by making another api request.

[image: Stripe Coupon Page]

Comment: The ID of the coupon is 20OFF.  There is no other ID that I can see.  I can't post a picture to a comment here, but I have the screenshot where Stripe says the ID is 20OFF

Comment: Are you sure? You might be right but when I look at a coupon I can see an id. I have added a screenshot but faked the coupon id with dev tools.

Comment: I added my screenshot to the original post so you could see it.  It looks exactly like yours but ID is 20OFF rather than what appears to be random characters for your ID.  Plus, I'm getting "Invalid Array" as an error rather than an error about an incorrect or unrecognized ID.  Makes me think it has more to do with formatting than the ID of the coupon.

Comment: Apologies - never saw the screenshot! Have you tried with the code I put in my answer / do you have the response if it didn't work?

Comment: I added the screenshot later. No need to apologize.

Comment: ah ok. Just noticed a typo in my answer (square bracket before `discounts` is missing), will update it, but looks like you've also tried that already.

Comment: This worked.  As you say, it is an array of arrays.  Even though there is only 1 element of the array, it needs to be surrounded by [ ] so that it will be parsed correctly as an array of arrays.  I think if I were sending multiple elements in the array it would have made more sense.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted in the end!

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
$stripe->invoices->update(
    $inv,
    [
       'discounts' => [
         ['coupon' => '20OFF']
        ]
     ]
);
```

As in, it's an array that then contains objects (in PHP those are both square brackets) and the objects refer to the coupon.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at my desk and I won't be for another 4 or 5 hours at least but I will try adding those other brackets in there.

Comment: Why would we need double brackets around `'coupon' => '20OFF'`

Comment: Because it's an array of objects. The second set of brackets is the object. If you imagine it as JSON, and with _multiple coupons_ if that's clearer,  it's `{discounts: [ { coupon:'20OFF' }, { coupon:'50OFF' }  ] }` . In PHP arrays and objects both use square brackets.